# Fit all controls to dialog [ All resolution ]

Tags: html, css, angular

I am mew to CSS. I want to achieve a responsive design ( No need in  mobile just all desktop sizes ).
So we have to display a form in a dialog and all the controls must be fit in to the dialog ( no bottom white space )

**Hint: So as I assume we can handle this by increasing text aria height but I don't know how ?**

Currently we have following design:

[image: Current UI looks like]

We want to like this:

[image: Like this in all browser]

Guys please suggest me how to handle this?

CSS :

```
 .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;

  .content {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 10px;

    grid-column-gap: 1.2rem;
    grid-row-gap: 0.1rem;

    grid-template-areas:
      "name name name version version version"
      "desc desc desc info info info"
      "disclouser disclouser disclouser rational rational rational"
    ;

    .name {
      grid-area: name;
    }

    .rational {
      grid-area: rational;
    }

    .version {
      grid-area: version;
    }

    .desc {
      grid-area: desc;
    }

    .info {
      grid-area: info;
    }

    .disclouser {
      grid-area: disclouser;
    }

    .buttons-container {
      grid-area: buttons;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }
  }
}
```

Html:

```
 <main class="container mat-typography" id="dialog-container-elememt">

    <div class="content">
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Could you please share your code with us?

Comment: @LinkinTED I have added css and html